# Grails maven plugin is not found at repository

Tags: java, maven, grails, pom.xml

I am trying to update my grails-maven-plugin from 2.4.6 to 4.0.3 and getting the below error.
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 only seem to have versions upto 2.4.6

```
Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:4.0.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:jar:4.0.3 (absent): Could not find artifact org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:jar:4.0.3 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: grails-plugin @ line 9, column 16
```

What should I do to fix this?.

pom.xml has the below plugin config

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
                <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <grailsVersion>${grails.version}</grailsVersion>
                    <webXml>${basedir}/web.xml</webXml>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <forkOptions>
                        <executable>java</executable>
                        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                    </forkOptions>
                    <webdriverBinaries>
                        <chromedriver>
                            <version>79.0.3945.36</version>
                            <architecture>${env.CIRCLECI != null ? 'X86_64' : (Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT || Environment.current == Environment.TEST) ? 'X86' : 'X86_64'}</architecture>
                        </chromedriver>
                        <geckodriver>0.24.0</geckodriver>
                    </webdriverBinaries>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>init</goal>
                            <goal>maven-clean</goal>
                            <goal>validate</goal>
                            <goal>config-directories</goal>
                            <goal>maven-compile</goal>
                            <goal>maven-test</goal>
                            <goal>maven-war</goal>
                            <goal>maven-functional-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the plugin source https://github.com/grails/grails-maven/tags the latest released version is 2.4.6.  I do not believe you should update this to version 4.0.3, as it does not exist.

Instead, you can set the grails version in the configuration per the documentation:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.grails</groupId>
<artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.3</version>
<configuration>
    <grailsVersion>2.3.10</grailsVersion>
    <!-- In the 2.4.3 release of grails-maven-plugin, you need to explicitly set the grailsVersion -->
    <!-- otherwise 2.4.2 will be used -->
    <!--<grailsVersion>2.4.3</grailsVersion>-->
</configuration>
```

(Pasted from https://github.com/grails/grails-maven/blob/master/README.md )

Note that this documentation is nine years old and may not be applicable to versions of grails released after that point.